# how to debug make

Tags: c, debugging, makefile

If make fails with: "bmake: don't know how to make blah", what/where is the best place to start looking for problems? why did it fail? What does it mean by "don't know"?

Comment: You don't have corresponding rule for `blah`. Not sure if it answers the question "how to debug", though…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [GNU Make Debugger](http://gmd.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

It means the Makefile doesn't have that target. It doesn't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

the Makefile should include all your source file like .c and .o (and .h if necessary)

and the point is that the compiling step should follow like this :

FileName ---> FileName.o ---> FileName.c

hope it does help you.

0r try search keyword "makefile" on google

it's not difficult to read it.